# missing angular.js file in bower_componets/angular / path, getting angular.min.js.gzip file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I have created a project using the  command

```
yo angular c3Chart
```

after successful scaffolding, In bower components i am getting angular.min.js.gzip file, for that getting error as "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined".

In index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

why this path is missing ,it has to come automatically after build. i tried adding manually it disappears after grunt serve command.

In index.html build:js is empty

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```